# Show Only One Specific Value In DropDown

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to only show one of the statuses in the dropdown in this particular view. In the controller for the get create method I have this:

```
ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.statuses, "StatusId", "StatusName");
```

I know the fourth option for select list can specify a specific selected item but what if I only want to show one of the items this time?

Here's the model:

```
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this means that you need to filter the db.statuses based on your condition?

Comment: Yeah what's the best way to do that?

Comment: what is your condition ? please paste the complete code which your are trying to fix

Comment: There's no other relevant code but I can post the model. One of the statuses is called "Pending Approval" that's the only one of 4 I want included.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle check answers hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `linq` to filter that specific value by using `where`

```
ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.statuses.Where(x=>x.StatusName == "Pending Approval"), "StatusId", "StatusName");
```

this will display only value which matches the condition. In this case you cannot use `.Single` because `new select` expects `list`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this I just hard coded data your will be coming from DB. You can add condition which you see is required in your case.

```
var status = new List<Status> {
                new Status { StatusId=1, StatusName="A" },
                new Status { StatusId=2, StatusName="B" },
                new Status { StatusId=3, StatusName="C" },
                new Status { StatusId=4, StatusName="D" },
};

var result = status.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StatusName.Equals("A", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));

if(result!=null)
{
    ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(result, "StatusId", "StatusName");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to select the `"Pending Approval"` name only if a certain condition exists.

```
if (yourCondition) 
{ 
    db.statuses = ((from ss in db.statuses 
                    where ss.StatusName == "Pending Approval" 
                    select ss).ToList()); 
}
```

This selects any status with the `StatusName` of `"Pending Approval"`.

Then you follow with your line:

```
ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.statuses, "StatusId", "StatusName");
```